# Insert & update sql data using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i've a registration form & im trying to insert data if 'ID' doesn't exists. its working fine. now im trying to update data if 'ID' already exists. it's not working at all & i couldn't find the error. here is the condition i set if ID exists or not:

```
function staff_detail_exist($ic) {    
    $result = null;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM apply WHERE staffid = '$ic'";
    $data = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($data) == 0) {    
        $result = "available";
    } else {    
        $result = "exist";
    }

    return $result;
}
```

and here is my insert & update function:

```
 if (staff_detail_exist($ic) == "available") {

    insert_staff_detail($ic, $name, $contact, $mail, $address, $paytype, $applicant);
    echo "Workshop application successful! You will be notified shortly via E-mail after confirmation! Thank You!";
} 
else if (staff_detail_exist($ic) == "exist") {

    update_staff_detail($ic, $name, $contact, $mail, $address, $paytype);
    echo  "Staff Details Updated!" ;
}

function insert_staff_detail($ic, $name, $contact, $mail, $address, $paytype, $applicant) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO apply (staffid, staffname, staffno, staffemail, staffaddress, paytype, applicant) VALUES ('$ic', '$name', '$contact', '$mail', '$address','$paytype', '$applicant')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}

function update_staff_detail($ic, $name, $contact, $mail, $address, $paytype){
    $sql = "UPDATE apply 
            SET staffname='$_POST[name]',
            staffno='$_POST[contact]',
            staffmail='$_POST[mail]',
            address='$_POST[address]',
            paytype='$_POST[paytype]'
            WHERE staffid='$_POST[ic]'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

any suggestion please? thanks!

Comment: This code would be vulnerable to an sql injection attack.

Comment: By not sanitizing data taken from the user before it is inserted into the database.

Comment: What I would tend to do would be to show the value of `$sql` in `update_staff_detail()` and then drop to a command line, fire up MySql (or whatever you use) and paste the `UPDATE` command there and see what it says E.g, " you have an error in your SQL syntax ... near <ERROR IS HERE> at line 1'. Also `SHOW WARNINGS;` and `SHOW ERRORS` ... hope that helps a little

Comment: @patricksweeney, i didn't get it bro. can you explain briefly, please?

Comment: Btw, is there a reason why `update_staff_detail()` is ignoring it's parameters and using the `$_POST` variables? Could that be your problem?

Comment: Any time to take into from the user, you need to make sure you sanitize the information. They may pass in information that drop all your tables in the DB, for example. Look at http://bobby-tables.com/ for a starting example.

Comment: @Atik We're not your "bros."

Comment: @njk, im sorry Sir. i never knew that calling an unknown person as 'bro' is a crime! I apologize..

Comment: It's not a crime, just impolite (but please, don't taze me for saying so ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Observation:** You must indicate when you receive POST variables. The `update_staff_detail` method should receive POST variables in the same way you get the `insert_staff_detail` method.

**Change:** Definition of `update_staff_detail`

**To:**

```
function update_staff_detail($ic, $name, $contact, $mail, $address, $paytype){
    $sql = "UPDATE apply 
            SET staffname='$name',
            staffno='$contact',
            staffmail='$mail',
            address='$address',
            paytype='$paytype'
            WHERE staffid='$ic' LIMIT 1";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Perhaps a `LIMIT 1` would be well suited for this.

Comment: Would help you enter the complete code you receive insert_staff_detail method from POST variables.

Comment: i used this to get values from from:
` $ic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ic']);
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
  $mail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
  $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
  $paytype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['paytype']);
  $applicant = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['applicant']);`